# gazelle+protobuf problem: does not have mandatory providers: 'GoLibrary'

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

From gazelle-generated BUILD files, I get the following error when I run `bazel build //foo/bar/protos/...:`

`ERROR:  .../foo/bar/protos/BUILD.bazel:15:17: in deps attribute of go_proto_library rule //foo/bar/protos:protos_go_proto: '//baz/quux/api:api_proto' does not have mandatory providers: 'GoLibrary'`

Both BUILD files have:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:def.bzl", "go_proto_library")
```

I have seen `https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/providers.rst`, but it was more confusing.

*I also asked this on the Gophers Slack, but there is very little traffic there.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that `//baz/quux/api:api_proto` is the wrong kind of target for the `deps` attribute of the `go_proto_library` rule (it does not "provide" the right information).

`//baz/quux/api:api_proto` is probably a `proto_library` target, and should be in the `protos` attribute instead of the `deps` attribute:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/proto/core.rst#go_proto_library